# Under Symfony, the locale seems to change without explanation

Tags: php, symfony, localization, twig, symfony-messenger

I have a Symfony 4 application in which I generate a PDF file using dompdf. In my twig files, I use [localizeddate](https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intl.html#localizeddate) to display a date. I want my date to be written in French.

```
<div>
    Date :
    <span>{{ myCustomDate | localizeddate('long', 'none') }}</span>
</div>
```

I use the twig template in two different services: one called by my browser, the other using [Messenger](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/components/messenger.html).

When I generate the PDF by using the "regular" browser way, the date is written in French.

> Date : 12 décembre 2020

But when I generate it using Messenger, the date is in English.

> Date : December 12, 2020

Would you know why?

Comment: set the locale `localizeddate('long', 'none', 'fr')`

Comment: The reason why is the translator gets the locale from the request if not explicitly specified. As far as I know, the request context is not passed to messenger. You can pass the locale manually and then use `localizeddate('long', 'none', my_locale)` where `my_locale` would be the variable you passed along.